# MSXML.XMLHTTPRequest Get Response Size limit

Tags: vba, xmlhttprequest, size, limit, getresponse

I am trying to parse an HTML to find information in web pages.

Everything worked fine, so far. It seems that there is a size limit to the request as I don't get all the HTML code:

```
Sub AAA(A As String, B As String, C As String)

   'Déclaration des variables
   Dim txt As String, url As String
   Dim ohttp As Object

   On Error Resume Next
   'instanciation de l'object MSXML2.XMLHTTP
   Set ohttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
   If Err <> 0 Then Set ohttp = CreateObject("MSXML.XMLHTTPRequest")

   'Gestion de l'erreur si l'instanciation n'a pas fonctionné
   If ohttp Is Nothing Then MsgBox "MSXML2.XMLHTTP not found", 16, "Error":       Exit Sub

   url = "http://www.aaa.com/" & A
   'execution de la demande
   With ohttp
      .Open "GET", url, False
      .send
      txt = .responseText
   End With
   Set ohttp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Do you know how I could get all the HTML code of a web page?

Thank you in advance,

Best regards,

Antoine

Comment: There is no real size limit which would truncate the response: can you explain exactly why you feel that's happening?  If you're printing the response to the Debug window then you should know that has a limit to the number of lines it will display.

Comment: Could you please share example URL, or truncated HTML sample. And also a value of `ohttp.GetAllResponseHeaders`. Edit the question and add that info.

Comment: Here is the website (for example with Apple quote): http://quotes.wsj.com/AAPL/financials/annual/income-statement

For the getAllResponseHeaders, here is what I get:

   Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

   X-Host: i-0a9e124b9836074e9

   X-Powered-By: Tesla

   Expires: Thu, 08 Feb 2018 17:55:55 GMT

   Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store

   Pragma: no-cache

   Date: Thu, 08 Feb 2018 17:55:55 GMT

   Connection: keep-alive

   Set-Cookie: wsjregion=europe; Domain=.wsj.com; Path=/; Expires=Sat, 10 Mar 2018 17:55:55 GMT

Comment: Actually, I can find for example the turnover of a quote but can't find the EBIT in the HTML code downloaded via vba. I continued to search and maybe it would be due to dynamic HTML? I read that websites download the HTML code when you scroll down. is there a way to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: If the page is dynamic then you'd need to use a different approach, such as automating IE.

Comment: Do you have more information? I am beginner in VBA. Thank you.

Comment: Google "VBA automate IE" or search the questions here on SO.

Comment: Great, I found what I needed. Thank you Tim W. ! :)